# Gerar notificação na Barra lateral do Windows para usuário específico?

Tags: delphi, redis

Estou utilizando o PubSub do Redis para criar um Chat Desktop e gostaria de gerar uma notificação na barra lateral do Windows para um usuário quando o mesmo recebesse uma mensagem.
Buscando na internet logo encontrei o seguinte código aqui (http://portal.tdevrocks.com.br/2015/12/01/tutorial-notificacoes-no-windows-10-com-delphi-10-seattle/)

```
var
  Notificacao : TNotification;
begin
    Notificacao := NotificationCenter1.CreateNotification;
    try
      Notificacao.Name      := 'Nome Notificacao';
      Notificacao.Title     := 'Título da Notificação';
      Notificacao.AlertBody := 'Corpo da Notificação';
      NotificationCenter1.PresentNotification(Notificacao);
    finally
      Notificacao.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Ele funciona, gera uma notificação, MAS o problema é que a notificação aparece também para o usuário que enviou a mensagem.
É possível notificar só o usuário que recebeu? Se sim podem me dar uma direção de como o fazer?

Comment: Você consegue identificar para quem é a notificação? Se algo como destinatario e o remetente? Se tem faz um if para validar para quem deve exibir

Comment: Consigo identificar usuário que envia e que recebe, vou tentar algumas coisas aqui. Obrigado.

Comment: @GabrielLocalhost Usando o esquema de PubSub do Redis, eu fiz uma validação onde se  o destinatário da mensagem for o meu usuário e o marcador de mensagem lida estiver vazio ele notifica.
Fiz alguns testes e funcionou, obrigado.

Comment: de nada @Diego_F